# Script to add and remove columns depending on the variable length of the line in a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cut

I have n number of records in a file karan.csv in the following format:

```
A=9607738162|B=9607562681|C=20200513191434|D=|F=959852599|G=MT|H=4012|I=4012|J=9607562681|K=947100410|
A=960299773008|B=9607793008|C=20200513191327|D=|E=ST|F=959852599|G=MO|H=2001|I=2001|J=9607793008|K=947100180|
A=9607704530|B=9607839496|C=20200513191730|D=|F=959852599|G=MT|I=5012|J=9607839496|K=|
```

Now if we notice, the number of columns are: 10, 11 & 9 respectively. This count is random within the file, however, the number of columns will remain the same.

Now, I wan to create a script that will remove $5 from that column (including the delimiter) if there are 11 columns in a line such that it looks exactly like the row with 10 columns

```
A=9607738162|B=9607562681|C=20200513191434|D=|F=959852599|G=MT|H=4012|I=4012|J=9607562681|K=947100410|
```

and, that adds "H=|" in $7 where the column count is 9

```
A=9607704530|B=9607839496|C=20200513191730|D=|F=959852599|G=MT|H=|I=5012|J=9607839496|K=|
```

Now I wrote the following code to achieve it:

```
for text in $(cat /tmp/karan.csv);do
  count=`awk -F"|" '{print NF-1}' $text`
  if [ $count == 9 ]
  then
  awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$7="|H"}1' $text >> /tmp/karantest2.csv
  elif [ $count == 10 ]
  then
  echo $text >> /tmp/karantest2.csv
  else
  awk -F"|" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}' $text >> /tmp/karantest2.csv
  fi
  done
```

But after debugging, I realised the script was not moving ahead after:

```
count=`awk -F"|" '{print NF-1}' $text`
```

Can any one please me regarding the same.

Regards

Comment: The variable `text` holds in each iteration one line of the CSV file. and you tell awk that this line is the name of a file to be processed. Of course there is no file of a name. I had expected that `awk` would then issue an error message, but I tried it out by invoking `awk non-existent-file`, and indeed, it did not complain, but instead waited on stdin for input to be processed.

Comment: I agree with you @user1934428. But is there a way to use awk for variables like '$text' rather than file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'|' '

BEGIN { OFS="|" }

NF==10 { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, "H=", $7, $8, $9, $10 }
NF==11 { print $0 }
NF==12 { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12 }

' karen.csv
```

Output for the sample input provided is:

```
A=9607738162|B=9607562681|C=20200513191434|D=|F=959852599|G=MT|H=4012|I=4012|J=9607562681|K=947100410|
A=960299773008|B=9607793008|C=20200513191327|D=|F=959852599|G=MO|H=2001|I=2001|J=9607793008|K=947100180|
A=9607704530|B=9607839496|C=20200513191730|D=|F=959852599|G=MT|H=|I=5012|J=9607839496|K=|
```

Comment: @KaranKohli. You are welcome. Please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A sed solution, which first inserts `H=|` on lines with 9 columns, then removes the 7th column on lines with 11 columns:

```sh
sed -E '/^([^\|]+\|){9}$/s/(([^\|]+\|){6})/\1H=\|/;/^([^\|]+\|){11}$/s/(([^\|]+\|){4})[^\|]+\|/\1/ inputfile
```

If you need a POSIX-compliant command, then

- since `-E` is not POSIX, you have to escape every `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `+` (and other special characters, which are not in this command), and un-escape `\|` to make it literal;
- since `\+` is not POSIX either, you need to use the more verbose `\{1,\}`.

Here's the POSIX-compliant command:

```sh
sed '/^\([^|]\{1,\}|\)\{9\}$/s/\(\([^|]\{1,\}|\)\{6\}\)/\1H=|/;/^\([^|]\{1,\}|\)\{11\}$/s/\(\([^|]\{1,\}|\)\{4\}\)[^|]\{1,\}|/\1/' inputfile
```

Comment: --E is an illegal option on solaris machine. And when i try to use -r, i get the same error

Comment: Hi

I'm not comfortable with sed commands, so i just copied and pasted your command (ofcourse changed the file name). It is just printing the file as it is without any modification without removing or adding any column in the file

Comment: Based on what I can reproduce [here](https://sed.js.org/#), the command I provided seems to be non POXIS-compliant, but I have no clue why. I'll give a look at it later today.

Comment: @KaranKohli, found. `\+` is not POSIX, so you have to use `\{1,\}` instead.